# Multiple checkboxes in CakePHP - how to set which are checked?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes in CakePHP's Add/Edit view, created with:

```
echo $this->Form->input('email_warning_chb', array('type'=>'select', 'multiple'=>'checkbox', 'label'=> __('Email notice'), 'class'=>'multiple-chb', 'options'=> array('title...'=>array( '5'=>'5 days', '15'=>'15 days', '30'=>'30 days', '60'=>'60 days');
```

My question is how to set which one are checked by default (ie. in thi example, 5, 15 and 60)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This was a better answer for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243537/cakephp-multiple-select-selected-is-not-working

Comment: This was a better answer for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168225/multiple-checkboxes-in-cakephp-how-to-set-which-are-checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks like this one

[cakephp: How to set checkbox to checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962463/cakephp-how-to-set-checkbox-to-checked)

where `$selected` contains the selected values

Answer (score 12):

As said in other answers, you should set the 'selected' option.
What some people don't mention is that your selected array should only contain the id in each element.
Example:

```
$selectedWarnings = $this->Warning->find('list', array(
  'fields' => array('id')
));


echo $this->Form->input('email_warning_chb', array(
    'label' => 'Email Notice',
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $warnings,
    'selected' => $selectedWarnings
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

in your controller you have to put the value like this:

```
$this->request->data['Model']['email_warning_chb'] = array(5,15,60);
```

and it will automatically display checkbox as selected.

Please ask if not work for you.