# cakephp pagination set condistion from array

Tags: cakephp, pagination, string-concatenation

I am using a form with several check boxes i need to display only those data which is in check box category.
How to write conditions for that.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($this->request->data['filter']['delivering']);$i++)
{   
$opt1=".'Gig.bangsalsodeliverings' => ".$this->request->data['filter']['delivering'][$i];
$opt2=$opt2.$opt1.',';
}
$options=array('conditions' => array($opt2));
$this->Paginator->settings = $options;
$agetGigsItem = $this->Paginator->paginate('Gig');
```

But getting error.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using a string contatenation instead of array to build the conditions array.
Also it's not clear to me if the filter delivering is a set of strings or integers.
I guess you can try:

```
// Merge the filters into a csv string
$filters = array();
foreach($this->request->data['filter']['delivering'] as $v){
    $filters[] = "'{$v}'";
}
$csv_filters = implode(",", $filters);

// Use the csv to make a IN condition
$this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => array(
    "Gig.bangsasodeliverings IN ({$csv_filters})",
));
```

Please note that sql injection can be made here, so prepare your data before creating $csv_filters.

Comment: thanx for reply actually i need filter same like ecommerce website like when i click on a brand then it display all product of same brand

Comment: i need a little more help i need to set selected those checkboxes which is selected. echo $this->Form->input('delivering.',array('hiddenField' => false,'type'=>'checkbox','value'=>$agetalsodelivering[$i]['Bangsalsodelivering']['name'],'div'=>'checkbox','class'=>'checkboxfilter','id'=>$agetalsodelivering[$i]['Bangsalsodelivering']['name'],'label'=>$agetalsodelivering[$i]['Bangsalsodelivering']['name']));

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168225/multiple-checkboxes-in-cakephp-how-to-set-which-are-checked